# Listen to a specific song on iPhone

Tags: iphone, music, streaming

What is the easiest way to stream/listen to a specific song for free, **that's not in your iTunes** library from an iPhone?

On a PC, I'd go on Deezer.com, launch spotify, try Hype Machine... But on the iPhone the "no-flash" policy makes it much harder.

I know some applications do this (i.e Deezer), but there's a price tag on it. And I sometimes use **YouTube**, but:

- It requires the screen to be turned on
- It's slower due to the loading of video (which I don't need)

I miss seeqpod.com, which had a mobile version that did exactly what I describe :( The solution should work outside the U.S. as well (which rules out Pandora).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GrooveShark's HTML5 mobile site](http://html5.grooveshark.com/) is the only way I know of.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen folks using [Pandora](http://pandora.com) on their iPhones.

And Sirius XM is offering a trial period for their satellite service on the iPhone and iPod touch.

I've found a fair number of songs on YouTube for which the "video" is a still image for the whole length.

Answer (score 1):

Phone your local radio station and request the song. Then use one of the many radio tuner apps to listen into it...

Answer (score 1):

[GoEar](http://goear.com) has an excellent collection of tunes which can be listened from any iDevice or similiar mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a file synch app.  [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/80), Files, whatever works for you.  Dropbox, just install it where you have a computer to run it. Files creates a webdav/http site for uploads.

Both (and probably other apps) use the native 'open this file' apis on the phone to play it.  You won't be able to have playlists, but you can play your one song.